# On the half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrices

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, combinatorial-designs

**Definition 1**: A Hadamard matrix is an $n\times n$ matrix $H$ whose entries are either $1$ or $-1$ and whose rows are mutually orthogonal.

**Definition 2**: A matrix $A$ is half-skew-centrosymmetric if there exist two square matrices $B$ and $C$ of order $n$ such that

\begin{equation}
      A = \begin{bmatrix}
        B & R C R \\
        C & -R B R
      \end{bmatrix}.
  \end{equation}

where $R$ is the reverse identity matrix.

One day I found that these two definitions can be considered simultaneously. For example, \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & -1
      \end{bmatrix} is the simplest half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix.

Here comes my questions:

> First, can you give some references about half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrices? Are there other names for these matrices?

> Second one is about construction methods. It is easy to figure out how to construct a half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order $2^k\cdot n$ based on a Hadamard matrix of order $n$ by using a variant of Sylvester's construction.
> Can you propose more methods to construct half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrices?

> Third, can you prove the following conjecture or give a counter-example?
>
> **Conjecture**: A half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix exists for $n=2$ or $n$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: The order of a Hadamard matrix must be $1,2$ or multiple of $4$. Also for some $B=C=H$ (Hadamard matrix of order $4n$), $A$ is order $8n$ Hadamard matrix. As mentioned in Wikipedia, the existence of such a matrix for all $4k$ is an open problem.

Comment: You can write the half skew centro symmetric as $X=RXR$ for $$R = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & R_n \\
-R_n & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_n$ be an $n×n$ Hadamard matrix and $R_n$ the $n×n$ reverse identity matrix.

The matrix $X= \begin{pmatrix}
H_n & R_nH_n \\
H_n & -R_nH_n
\end{pmatrix}$ has entries of length $1$ and $$XX^* = 2nI_{2n} + ((nI_n - R_nH_nH_n^*R_n) \otimes R_2)$$ which is simply $2nI_{2n}$ so it is a Hadamard matrix. Permute the last $n$ columns with $R_n$ and you have it in the form you give. This gives half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrices of twice the size of a Hadamard matrix. (It also works for complex Hadamard matrices or even Hadamard matrices over *-rings)

Another construction (edit): suppose we apply the [Paley construction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction) II to a finite field with $q=4k+1$ elements giving an $2n×2n$ Hadamard matrix $H= \begin{pmatrix}
H_1 & H_2 \\
H_3 & H_4
\end{pmatrix} $ after permuting the odd columns and rows to the first $n$ rows/columns, the even as last $n$ AND put the first even row/column at the last position. Define $X := X_{i,j} = (i-j)^{0.5(q-1)}$ (in the finite field this is $\pm 1$ with zero diagonal and symmetric because $-1$ is a square). Note that $X_{i,j+k}=X_{j+k,i}=X_{n-i+k,n-j}$. Then for Paley construction II, using $j$ as all-ones vector $$H_2^T = H_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
j & X-I \\
-1 & j^T
\end{pmatrix}$$ $$H_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & j^T \\
j & X+I
\end{pmatrix}$$ $$H_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
-X-I & -j \\
-j^T & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$The $H_i$ now have the properties $R_nH_2R_n = H_3$ and $-R_nH_1R_n = H_4$ due to our note above. Thus $H$ is a half-skew-centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix!

Comment: The lowest dimension divisible by 4 not covered by these constructions is $44$